# $N\trianglelefteq G$, how to show that $G/N$ is abelian if $aba^{-1}b^{-1} \in N$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Say $N$ is a normal subgroup of the group $G$, and $aba^{-1}b^{-1} \in N$ for $a,b \in G$.  How would I prove that the factor group $G/N$ is abelian?  The factor group $G/N$ is the cosets of $N$ in $G$.

Comment: Nothing more than definition pushing: $G/N$ is abelian iff $(aN)(bN) = (bN)(aN)$ iff $(ab)N = (ba)N$ iff $(ab)(ba)^{-1} \in N$ iff $aba^{-1}b^{-1} \in N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p:G\rightarrow G/N$ the projection map, for every $a,b\in G$, $p(aba^{-1}b^{-1})=p(a)p(b)p(a)^{-1}p(b)^{-1}=1$. This implies that $p(a)p(b)=p(b)p(a)$b and $G/N$ is commutative since $p$ is surjective.

Comment: Why does $p(a^{-1}) = p(a)^{-1}$?  Is this a property of factor groups? Also, why does $p(a)p(b)p(a)^{-1}p(b)^{-1}=1$?

Comment: $p$ is a morphism of groups.

Answer (score 2):

$(bN)(aN) = baN = (e_Gba)N = (e_GN)((ba)N)$

$= N((ba)N) = ((aba^{-1}b^{-1})N)((ba)N)$ (since $aba^{-1}b^{-1} \in N$)

$= ((aba^{-1}b^{-1})(ba))N = abN = (aN)(bN)$.

Answer (score 0):

abN=(aN)(bN)=(bN)(aN)=baN implies abellian, right?
It's equivalent to $a^{-1} b^{-1} abN=N$ or $a^{-1} b^{-1} ab\in N$. Is it clear now